# A way to display links and the associated pages they lead to?

Tags: 2007, pages, content-and-structure, team-sites

I am looking at creating a map of sorts of our SP site.  We have a numerous admins for the site and some so a naming convention was deveoped but never fully adheared to.  I am looking to start at the home page and get a list of all the links on the page and thier corresponding destinations, to better understand where things went wrong and to highlight what should be modified.  Is there a view on the backside of SP that automatically can do this? Or will i need to continue to manually gather the info?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correct, what you want is a site map of your SharePoint 2007. This can be done following the guide [Creating A SharePoint 2007 Site Map](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/74321.aspx).